# S3 PutObject with KMS encryption fails with 403 "Access Denied" error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I've been trying to do a PutObject call to AWS S3 while utilizing server-side encryption with a KMS key, but the call keeps failing with a 403 code and the message says "Access Denied".

Here's the C# code I'm using the make the call:

```
const string fileName = "test.txt";
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        sw.Write("letsseeifthisworks");

        var por = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = _bucketname,
            Key = fileName,
            InputStream = stream,
            ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AWSKMS,
            ServerSideEncryptionKeyManagementServiceKeyId = _kmsKeyId
        };

        var response = _s3Client.PutObject(por);
    }
}
```

Here's what the HTTP request looks like:

```
PUT https://notarealcorp.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/test.txt HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain
x-amz-server-side-encryption: aws:kms
x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id: arn:aws:kms:us-west-1:<account>:key/<kms-key-guid>
User-Agent: aws-sdk-dotnet-45/3.3.16.2 aws-sdk-dotnet-core/3.3.21.6 .NET_Runtime/4.0 .NET_Framework/4.0 OS/Microsoft_Windows_NT_6.1.7601_Service_Pack_1 ClientSync
host: notarealcorp.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
X-Amz-Date: 20180109T072431Z
X-Amz-Decoded-Content-Length: 18
X-Amz-Content-SHA256: STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<access-key>/20180109/us-west-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;user-agent;x-
amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-decoded-content-length;x-amz-server-side-encryption;x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id, Signature=<signature>
Content-Length: 191
Expect: 100-continue

12;chunk-signature=<another-signature>
letsseeifthisworks
0;chunk-signature=<yet-another-signature>
```

And here's the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
x-amz-request-id: <request-id>
x-amz-id-2: <host-id>
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 09 Jan 2018 07:24:31 GMT
Connection: close
Server: AmazonS3

f3
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>request-id</RequestId><HostId>host-id</HostId></Error>
0
```

These are the IAM permissions I have set up. First, S3:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and then KMS:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I comment out the encryption, the call goes through and I can see the file being created.

I'm unsure what the 'Access Denied' means. What resource am I being denied access to? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the 'grant' permissions on the key policy, which lets you delegate key permissions to AWS services which support KMS server-side encryption. Once I added that, it worked.

```
{
  "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account>:user/<user>"
  },
  "Action": [
    "kms:CreateGrant",
    "kms:ListGrants",
    "kms:RevokeGrant"
  ],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
    "Bool": {
      "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

More information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html#key-policy-default-allow-users

Comment: Using`"Resource": "*"` could be too open. I know it shows example like that in the docs, but you should use an actual KMS Key ARN there (or a list of them) not `*`. If the Principle user is you then maybe that's OK for an admin level permission, but if it is an IAM role then you are granting the service access to any and all keys in KMS. Maybe it's OK for a small project with only 1 key, but as a better practice you should probably have different keys for different things.

Answer (score 2):

AWS does not provide details for Access Denied. This is normal in well designed systems for security purposes, but this is not helpful to developers.

Verify your KMS key works using the AWS CLI.

```
aws s3 cp SourceFile s3://mybucket/DestinationFile --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id <ReplaceWithYourKeyId>
```

If the CLI works then there is a problem with your code (which I don't see). If the CLI also reports an error, then you probably have a KMS Key Users issue.

When you created the KMS Key, you set the Usage Permissions for the key. Go to the AWS IAM Console. Double check that the IAM User that the code is running under has permissions to use the KMS key. Look under "Key Users".

If you have defined the Key Users correctly, go to the S3 Console and test uploading a file using the same KMS key and make sure that it works.

Comment: I'm a bit of an IAM noob, so the 'Key Users' suggestion helped. Turns out that the key was created without 'grant' privileges, so it could only do client-side encryption. Once I added the kms:CreateGrant, kms:ListGrants, kms:RevokeGrant permissions, it worked! Thanks John!